# ¿How to calculate a difference between rows in a select in SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like your help for a Oracle sql construction.

Let's say I have below database tables and descriptions:
Store: store the information related to all new customers
       country allows to take two values: “Argentina” / “Brasil”

CustomerBOM: stores historical clientes
       Date: First date of each month (1/01/2017, 1/02/2017…)
       Client: a customer who’s subscription is up to date.

[image: Here is a better table description.]

Now I have to answer this question:
Which is the quantity for each month?

The code I've made so far is shown below:

```
select date,  
from CustomerBOM t1, Store t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID
group by date
having 
order by date asc
```

Can you please guide me on how to have a full list with the difference between each month?

Edit:
This is how it should look like the output of the sentence:

```
Month         Difference 
January       100 (total clients) 
February      20 (120 clients from February - 100 clients from January)
March         60 (180 clients from March - 120 clients from February)
```

Thanks,
Nicolás.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please post some sample data and desired result?

Comment: You can join the table with itself with the key = key and date = date -1 month and get the calculations you want to do in the select.

Comment: What "quantity" are you trying to determine?

Comment: Quantity is the different between the total amount of customers from the month selected - total amount of customers from the previous month.
Expected output will look something like this:
Month          Difference
January       100 (total clients)
February      20  (120 clients from February - 100 clients from January)

Comment: You can use LEAD() function to refer to the previous line in order to perform your calculation

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. How can I mark this as correct for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') customer_month,  count(1) number_of_customers
from CustomerBOM t1, 
     Store t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID
group by to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
order by to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Comment: Thanks, the output of that sentence will actually bring the amount of customers for each month.
In face, I need to add some calculation to that sentence in order to have another column with the variance for each month.
Please see my first post edited for more details.

Comment: Hi,
OK, could you try this?

select customer_month, no_of_customers, no_of_customers - lag(no_of_customers, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY customer_month) difference_from_previous
from
(
select to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM') customer_month,  count(1) no_of_customers
from CustomerBOM t1, 
     Store t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID
group by to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM')
order by to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY/MM')   
)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am not sure why newline is not showing after I submit my comment. Anybody knows how to enter newline in the comment so that my SQL query is nicely formatted?
Thanks..